# How to save Word doc to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-streaming

I am new to Hadoop and wanted to know the easiest way for someone to save a word document file that automatically gets sent to HDFS

Answer (score 1):

In order to put data on your HDFS you need to execute some command lines. This link (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html) is describing what you need and the command should be :

> hdfs dfs -put localfile /user/hadoop/hadoopfile

PS : If you want the transfert to be automatic, you could write a bash script

Comment: A bash script is  program write with the bash langage. It allow you to automate some tasks with ease but you have to learn the langage [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html)